# I have a problem with reading from a file

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    fstream file, save_file;
    vector<string> words;

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        file >> words[i];

    cout << words[0];

    return 0;
}
```

I want to save these words in a vector, but I can't. I have a message: zad1.exe is already runing! Please close it first to compile successfully! I don;t know why.

Comment: So many issues here, only addressing the critical ones: you have not constructed the `fstream` before you started using it and you are indexing into an empty default constructed vector.

Comment: The `std::vector<std::string>` is initially empty. If you want to read words into it, you'll need to increase its size. I would recommend reading into a temporary variable and then using `vector`'s `push_back()` method. Also, I **strongly** recommend that you test whether the input was successful before you do anything with the value: `if (file >> temp) { ... }`

Comment: `vector<string> words;` is an empty vector. Accessing any index is out-of-bound access. You have to add elements e.g. with `push_back()`.

Comment: Unless there is exactly 1000 items in the file maybe you want a while loop instead.

Comment: Please first read basics of FILE [I/O](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/) and STL [vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/). I am sure after this, you can debug all the errors which @M.A stated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{

    std::fstream file("test.txt"), save_file;

    std::vector<std::string> words;
    std::string line;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        file >> line;
        words.push_back(line);
    }


    std::cout << words[0];

    return 0;
}
```

Instead of test.txt write your file path

Answer (score 0):

On some operating systems you cannot write to a file if that file is a running program. That is what the error message is telling you. You are creating a program called `zad1.exe` and it is currently running so you cannot create a new version of `zad1.exe` until you stop the version that is already running.

Are you working on Windows? If so then use the task manager to kill any versions of `zad1.exe` that you can see.

Plus you have **many** problems with the code as pointed out in the comments above. But the first task is to kill those running programs.